# I can't add more than 10 numbers values DWord in registry

Tags: c#, registry

I can't add this value because the range is too high, can you help me
the line code is :

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Pa
rameters", "A", (object)4026527743, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "RegistryValueKind.QWord" for long, it is for 64-bit binary number. DWord is for 32-bit binary number.

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters",
"A", 4026527743, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```